# Autosys Job Configuration

Tags: autosys

What is the behavior of the job if I am giving Dependency and Schedule on the same job?

Suppose a job J2 is dependent on J1 on s(J1)|f(J1) and is scheduled at 18:00.
If the job J1 is force started at 15:00 and is success at 15:05. What will happen to the job J2 will it get start at 15:05 or will it wait till 18:00?

Thanks in advance,
Suresh Reddy M

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Job2 will wait until 18:00 to become "Active", then will check the dependency on s(Job1).  If Job1 is in success at that time, Job2 will run.

Answer (score 0):

The run time of a job (or a box) is always based on the condition (dependency) and the schedule set to it. If either of the two is not met yet, then the job will not run. So in your question, the job2 will not run until 18:00.